# Spring 3 MVC capability for JSTL jsp option group label

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I am a newbie to Spring  and I want to create "option group select"  But I am unable to do this.

I want an output as following but in HTML type  saying

```
<select name="..." value"...">
 <optgroup label="Category 1">
  <option ... />
  <option ... />
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Category 2">
  <option ... />
  <option ... />
  </optgroup>
 </select>

 General
       movies
       hobbies        
 Games
      football
      basketball

 Images
      officePics
      familyPics
      PresntationPics

 RingTones
      pop
      classical
      jazz
```

jsp code 
Edited : Correct one

```
   <form:select multiple="single" path="servicemodule" id="servicemodule">
     <form:option value="None" label="--Select--" />
      <c:forEach var="service" items="${servicemodule}">
       <optgroup label="${service.key}">
       <form:options items="${service.value}"/>        
       </optgroup>
      </c:forEach>        
    </form:select>
```

Controller code :
There are 4 main categories and under each of these there can be many subCategories. These can be retrieved from getServiceModuleList method. But I am not getting idea where to implement the loop to store different subcategories under their respective main category.

```
 @Autowired
         private ServiceModule servicemodule;
```

Edited: Correct @ModelAttribute

```
        @ModelAttribute("servicemodule")
    public Map<String,List<String>> populateService() {

        String[][] mainCategory = new String[7][2];

        mainCategory[0][0]= "General"; mainCategory[0][1]= "general1234";
        mainCategory[1][0]= "Games"; mainCategory[1][1]= "games1234";
        mainCategory[2][0]= "Images"; mainCategory[2][1]= "images1234";
        mainCategory[3][0]= "Ringtones"; mainCategory[3][1]= "ringtone1234";

        Map<String,List<String>> serviceModule= 
        new LinkedHashMap<String,List<String>>();


        List<String> subCategory=new ArrayList<String>();

        List<ServicesPojo> services=
        servicemodule.getServiceModuleList("1",mainCategory[0][1],"0");
        for(ServicesPojo serviceName: services)
        {
            subCategory.add(serviceName.getServiceName().trim());
        }
        serviceModule.put(scats[0][0],subService);
        return serviceModule;
}
```

Edited: Got the Answer for Loop

```
    for(int i=0;i<mainCategory.length;i=i+2){
    List<String> subCategory=new ArrayList<String>();

        List<ServicesPojo> services=
        servicemodule.getServiceModuleList("1",mainCategory[0][i],"0");
        for(ServicesPojo serviceName: services)
        {
            subCategory.add(serviceName.getServiceName().trim());
        }
        serviceModule.put(mainCategory[i][0],subCategory);
      }
```

Model
This has the main error  whether I should keep only String or List Confused!!

Edited: Now Corrected one

```
  private List<String> servicemodule;

  public List<String> getServicemodule() {
    return servicemodule;
      }

public void setServicemodule(List<String> servicemodule) {
    this.servicemodule = servicemodule;
     }
```

Error Description

```
  org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: 
  Invalid property 'serviceModule' of bean class 
  [springx.practise.model.SiteModel]: Bean property 'serviceModule' 
  is not readable or has an invalid getter method: 
  Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Solved!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch you case: `servicemodule != serviceModule`.

The `<c:foreEach>` loop isn't correct either: it uses `itemGroup` both for `var` and `varStatus`, and `itemGroup` is never used inside the loop. Instead, `serviceModule` is used, but is not defined anywhere.

And I have a hard time understanding your code, one of the reasons being that you use the same name for very different things and don't pluralize attributes of type List.

```
private ServiceModule servicemodule;
...
Map<String,List<String>> serviceModule
...
private List<String> servicemodule;
...
<form:select multiple="single" path="serviceModule" id="serviceModule">
...
<c:forEach var="itemGroup" items="${servicesModule}" varStatus="itemGroup">
```

No wonder you lost yourself.

Comment: Well Spotted mate!! Also corrected my jstl tag .. and I got the result.. Sorry and apologies for my same name variables.. I am learning MVC and changing variablenames as per your suggestion!! cheers.

Comment: Can you also suggest about how to use the loop inside Controller.. each time I use, I get ArrayIndexOutOfboundsException.. when it try for all the main categories!

Comment: Found out the silly mistake in loop...  my question is corrected with answer now!! Thanks for identifying the Silly Case mistake!!